# Member Variable / public property null on postback

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I have a sandboxed visual web part (created in VS2012) when I initially load my web part and its child controls I set myProperty to a value retrieved from the database.  When I fill out the relevant form sections and click an update button the postback indicates that the myProperty is null.

How do I persist myProperty between postbacks?

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the property? In asp.net there are a couple of ways to store information on postbacks, like ViewState or Session.

Please see this thread for more info regarding those [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388403/how-to-keep-data-through-postbacks)